# What happens if hash is unique but hash % size is same in hash table?

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

Recently I'm studying hash table, and understand the basis is

1. create an array, for example

   `hashtable ht[4];`
2. hash the key

   `int hash = hash_key(key);`
3. get the index

   `int index = hash % 4`
4. set to hashtable

   `ht[index] = insert_or_update(value)`

And I know there is hash collision problem, if `key1` and `key2` has same hash, they go to same `ht[index]`, so `separate chaining` can solve this.

keys with same hash go to same bucket, these keys will be stored in a linked list.

My question is, what happens if hash is different, but modulus is same?

For example,

```
hash(key1): 3
hash(key2): 7
hash(key3): 11
hash(key4): 15
```

so index is 3, these keys with different hash and different key go to same bucket

I search google for some hash table implementation, it seems they don't deal with this situation. Am I overthought? Anything wrong?

For example, these implementations:

https://gist.github.com/tonious/1377667#file-hash-c-L139

http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)HashTables.html?highlight=%28CategoryAlgorithmNotes%29#CA-552d62422da2c22f8793edef9212910aa5fe0701_156

redis:
https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/dict.c#L488

nginx:
https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/core/ngx_hash.c#L34

they just compare if key is equal

Comment: The modulus is what determines the bucket, and most of the time the hash will be different.  In any case, two entries mapping to the same bucket is a collision.

Comment: OT Tip: Modding by a prime rather than 4 as in `hash % 4` makes for a better index will less collision likelihood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two objects' keys hash to the same bucket, it doesn't really matter if it's because they have the same hash, or because they have different hashes but they both map (via modulo) to the same bucket. As you note, a collision that occurs because of either of these situations is commonly dealt with by placing both objects in a bucket-specific list.

When we look for an object in a hashtable, we are looking for an object that shares the same key. The hashing / modulo operation is just used to tell us *in which bucket we should look* to see if the object is present. Once we've found the proper bucket, we still need to compare the keys of any found objects (i.e., the objects in the bucket-specific list) directly to be sure we've found a match.

So the situation of two objects with different hashes but that map to the same bucket works for the same reason that two objects with the same hashes works: we only use the bucket to find *candidate* matches, and rely on the key itself to determine a true match.